# How can I solve java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.axis.monitor.SOAPMonitorService?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

```
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8099"]
Jul 19, 2021 1:35:45 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Jul 19, 2021 1:35:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 444 ms
Jul 19, 2021 1:35:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Jul 19, 2021 1:35:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.61
Jul 19, 2021 1:35:46 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jul 19, 2021 1:35:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet [SOAPMonitorService] as unavailable
Jul 19, 2021 1:35:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [SOAPMonitorService] in web application [/myapp] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.axis.monitor.SOAPMonitorService
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1358)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1180)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:545)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1044)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:985)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5189)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1402)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)

Jul 19, 2021 1:35:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet [AdminServlet] as unavailable
Jul 19, 2021 1:35:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [AdminServlet] in web application [/myapp] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.axis.transport.http.AdminServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1358)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1180)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:545)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1044)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:985)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5189)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1402)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

this is my log in tomcat

It says the class org.apache.axis.monitor.SOAPMonitorService cannot be found, but I can't figure out why or where this error comes from. I am wondering how to solve this error.

The java version is 1.8, the Tomcat version is 8.5, and the Dynamic web module is set to 3.1 when creating Dynamic web service.
Eclipse version is 2021-06.

Comment: Looks like somehow the Axis jars have not been properly included. Make sure you get Axis, it has org.apache.axis.monitor.SOAPMonitorService and it gets deployed with your app